# Need to delete node_modules every time a new package is installed in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

We've recently started working on a project with create-react-app, but whenever someone adds a new package and commits those changes, we have to delete node_modules and install them again, even though we used yarn install.

What happens is, if I add one package, let's say "yarn add uuid" and commit both yarn.lock and package.json, when another dev pulls those changes and runs "yarn", it "installs" everything, and when he/she runs "yarn start" it will complain "Cannot find module 'uuid'".
Even when they add again "yarn add uuid", when they run "yarn start" it'll complain again.
The solution we saw was to delete node_modules and run "yarn install" again, but we have to do it every time.

I've never faced it before, I even thought it was something to do with my computer, but we're three devs facing the same problem.

We're using node v14.18.1, yarn 1.22.17 and react-scripts 4.0.3
we're all using yarn, I even added only-allow to only allow yarn

Comment: What happens when you do `yarn` (before deleting node_modules)? Yarn should say it installs the new package. The package should also be in node_modules. What if you use `npm install` instead?

Comment: Using npm is throwing an error "failed to load plugin "@typescript-eslint"". I had googled it and found out it's a problem with eslint 8 and typescript-eslint, but with yarn it doesn't happen. I just remembered that I was also having problems with eslint 8 and react-scripts, so I had to add "SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true" on my .env file, could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem by updating react-scripts ^5, they've upgraded the webpack version and I think it did the trick.